# Create Provider failed

Tags: java, bukkit

I want to implement my API with:

```
private boolean setupGameAPI() {
    if (getServer().getPluginManager().getPlugin("GameAPI") != null) {
        System.out.println("GameAPI found");
        RegisteredServiceProvider<GameAPI> GameAPIProvider = getServer().getServicesManager().getRegistration(GameAPI.class);
        if (GameAPIProvider != null) {
            gameapi = GameAPIProvider.getProvider();
            System.out.println("GameAPIProvider found");
        } else {
            System.out.println("GameAPIProvider not found");
        }
        return (gameapi != null);
    } else {
        System.out.println("GameAPI not found");
    }
    return false;
}
```

The output is:

```
[16:55:07] [Server thread/INFO]: GameAPI found
[16:55:07] [Server thread/INFO]: GameAPIProvider not found
```

The question how can I do it so that `GameAPIProvider` is not null? Maybe I have to add something in my API.

Answer (score 0):

Register it.

```
// This block of code is a demonstration of
// how you register the service manager in your API.
ServicesManager sm = getServer().getServicesManager();

GameAPI service = getMyGameAPI(); 

sm.register(GameAPI.class, service, this, priority);
```

Comment: I added this in my API;
getServer().getServicesManager().register(GameAPI.class, gameapi, this, ServicePriority.Normal);
It never gives null, but I cant use the Methods in my GameAPI class, there comes only NullPointerExceptions